# Populate wx.StaticText controls with dictionary key:value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary, wxpython

I have a wxPython GUI application that contains 13 pairs of StaticText controls that I would like to be able to set labels for problematically.

In terms of regression analysis, each pair of StaticText controls represents an independent variable and its coefficient. These key:value pairs are currently stored in a python dictionary, allowing me to use dictionary comprehension for much of my work.

Right now, I am struggling to display the contents of my python dictionary inside of my GUI. Any thoughts?

I am happy concatenating the key:value pair inside 1 StaticText control label, as I think it would be less messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure there are lots of different ways to do this. I would probably use a ListCtrl or better yet, ObjectListView. But I went ahead and created an example using StaticText controls:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.createControls()
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def createControls(self):
        """"""
        myDict = {"var1":"co-eff1", "var2":"co-eff2",
                  "var3":"co-eff3", "var4":"co-eff4",
                  "var5":"co-eff5", "var6":"co-eff6",
                  "var7":"co-eff7", "var8":"co-eff8",
                  "var9":"co-eff9", "var10":"co-eff10",
                  "var11":"co-eff11", "var12":"co-eff12",
                  "var13":"co-eff13"}
        for key in myDict:
            lblOne = wx.StaticText(self, label=key)
            lblTwo = wx.StaticText(self, label=myDict[key])

            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            sizer.Add(lblOne, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            sizer.Add(lblTwo, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
            self.mainSizer.Add(sizer)

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Frame Example",
                          size=(400,400))
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

If you want to see what a ListCtrl looks like, go and download the wxPython demo package and look up the ListCtrl demo. For ObjectListView, you can read my [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/23/wxpython-using-objectlistview-instead-of-a-listctrl/).

Comment: (Try again since linebreaks do not work in comments and edit is time limited.) To get both key and value, you can use `for key, value in myDict.items():` (or `.iteritems()` in Py2), then `label=value` in the loop.

Comment: Hey Mike, your blog has been a great resource! Cheers mate. Glad to see you around one of my questions.

Comment: After configuring StaticText to work, I have to agree with you that ListCtrl or ObjectListView will be better... now to figure that out!

Comment: @ Terry - sorry, I missed the "key, value" part. Yeah, you can certainly do it that way.